# boost and nginx compatible?

Tags: 7, caching

Is the boost module compatible with nginx ? Or does boost support nginx integration? If so where can one find the default nginx rules for installing boost?

The module requires installation using htaccess but nginx doesn't use htaccess it utilizes virtualhosts directives to manage the site.

I was able to find [this](http://drupal.org/node/244072) resource but it's from 2008 and it's for drupal 6. I know the rewriting rules have changed only slightly.

Comment: htaccess to nginx converter: http://is.gd/lU4DBq
Probably mickeytown2 will come and provide a perfect answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer. Boost and nginx are compatible.

Perusio provides a [pretty detailed configuration](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx/blob/D7/apps/drupal/drupal_boost.conf) setup for boost.

Comment: I think you meant "boost and nginx" are compatible :)